# Two foreach replacement JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Could you please recommend the more elegant way of handling these case?

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const getCombinations = () => {
  const combinations = [];
  arr1.forEach(el1 => {
    arr2.forEach(el2 => {
      combinations.push({
        el1,
        el2
      });
    });
  });
  return combinations;
};

console.log(getCombinations());
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything more elegant in vanilla JS, although there may be third-party libraries that will do it in one function.

Comment: There’s nothing particularly inelegant about this. I wouldn’t recommend `flatMap` (more copying, not more readability). `combinations.push({el1, el2});` on one line does help though IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const getCombinations = (a, b) => 
  a.flatMap(el1 => b.map(el2 => ({ el1, el2 })));

const result = getCombinations(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slightly more dynamic aproach by taking the cartesian product first and then map the objects with the wanted properties.

```js
const
    cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
    takeKeys = keys => a => Object.assign(...a.map((v, i) => ({ [keys[i]]: v })))
    array1 = [1, 2, 3],
    array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = [array1, array2]
        .reduce(cartesian)
        .map(takeKeys(['el1', 'el2']));
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```